# Delete the last line of a file using perl

Tags: perl, unix

```
sed '$d' $file;
```

Using this command doesn't seem to work, as `$` is a reserved symbol in Perl.

Comment: Escape the character with a backslash? `\`sed '\$d' file\`;`

Comment: Why are you trying to `sed` from within `perl` anyway? This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I want to read a file and delete the first and last lines, and use the remaining lines for doing some processing. Is there a way that I can use both the commands together

Comment: Deleting the last line of a file is a strange thing to do. Why was it written in the first place?

Comment: Do you want to modify the file, or do you just want to ignore those lines when you process it?

Comment: @Borodin , I don't want to modify the file, I just want to skip those lines while processing.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know why are you using `sed` into Perl. Perl itself have standard module to delete last line from a file.

Use the standard (as of v5.8) `Tie::File` module and delete the last element from the tied array:

```
use Tie::File;

tie @lines, Tie::File, $file or die "can't update $file: $!";
delete $lines[-1];
```

Comment: `pop @lines` is better, as `delete $lines[$i]` won't work for anything other than the last element of the array. You also need `untie @lines` to flush the change back to the file

Comment: @F.Hauri: From the module's documentation: **The file is** ***not*** **loaded into memory, so this will work even for gigantic files.**

Comment: @Borodin ... but `Tie::File` could'nt work with `STDIN`!

Comment: @F.Hauri: If STDIN is opened to a *file* then it will work fine. If not then deleting the last line makes no sense

Comment: @Borodin Yes it could make sens is STDIN is piped from another command.

Comment: @F.Hauri: You can't delete data from a pipe as it is read only. Besides, the OP explicitly says a *file*

Comment: @Borodin When you pipe to pipe, *deleting lines* make sens, like `sed -e 1d;25d;$d`

Answer (score 5):

#### Last line only

The closest syntax seem to be:

```
perl -ne 'print unless eof()'
```

This will act like `sed`, ie: without the requirement of reading the whole file into memory and could work with *FIFO* like `STDIN`.

See:

```
perl -ne 'print unless eof()' < <(seq 1 3)
1
2
```

or maybe:

```
perl -pe '$_=undef if eof()' < <(seq 1 3)
1
2
```

#### First and last lines

```
perl -pe '
    BEGIN {
        chomp(my $first= <>);
        print "Something special with $first\n";
    };
    do {
        chomp;
        print "Other speciality with $_\n";
        undef $_;
    } if eof();
  ' < <(seq 1 5)
```

will render:

```
Something special with 1
2
3
4
Other speciality with 5
```

#### Shortest: first and last line:

```
perl -pe 's/^/Something... / if$.==1||eof' < <(seq 1 5)
```

will render:

```
Something... 1
2
3
4
Something... 5
```

Try this:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$s=join"|",qw|1 3 7 21|;};
          if ($.=~/^($s)$/||eof){s/^/---/}else{s/$/.../}' < <(seq 1 22)
```

... something like `sed` command:

```
sed '1ba;3ba;7ba;21ba;$ba;s/$/.../;bb;:a;s/^/---/;:b' < <(seq 1 22)
```

#### In a script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

sub something {
    chomp;
    print "Something special with $_.\n";
}

$_=<>;
something;

while (<>)  {
    if (eof) { something; }
    else { print; };
}
```

will give:

```
/tmp/script.pl < <(seq 1 5)
Something special with 1.
2
3
4
Something special with 5.
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope you are trying to execute the 'sed' command from the middle of a perl script. I would recommend not to use this approach because it will work only in non-windows systems. Below is a perl'ish approach in which you can process first and last lines only rather than spending effort to delete file contents. Thank you.

Assuming "myfile.txt" as the input file:

```
open (FH, "<", "myfile.txt") or die "Unable to open \"myfile.txt\": $! \n";

$i = 1;

while(<FH>){
    next if ($i++ == 1 or eof);
    # Process other lines
    print "\nProcessing Line: $_";    
}

close (FH);

print "\n";
1;
```

myfile.txt -

```
# First line
This is the beginning of comment free file.
Hope this is also the line to get processed!
# last line
```

Result -

```
Processing Line: This is the beginning of comment free file.

Processing Line: Hope this is also the line to get processed!
```

Comment: Well.. thanks for directing.. the below line will also work if we remove $i. next if ($. == 1 or eof);

Answer (score -1):

This works for me, and it also removes unwanted empty lines at start and end.

```
use File::Slurp;
my $fileContent = read_file($csv_file);
my @lines = grep /\S/, split /\n/, $fileContent;
pop @lines;
$fileContent = join '', map "$_\n", @lines;
print $fileContent;
write_file($csv_file, $fileContent);
```